# Select-String Not Working In Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I am trying to pull a string from a `reference` object in Powershell, but I am having no success. Here is what I am trying:

```
Select-String -Pattern "ro.product"  -InputObject $output.Value
```

I have also tried:

```
Select-String -InputObject $output.Value  -Pattern "ro.product"
```

`$output.value` is a list of build properties from an Android phone. I have use the `.getType()` function to determine what the type is, and `$output.value` is a string, and `$output` is a `reference`. I'm new to Powershell and I'm hoping that someone can provide some direction on this. Every reference I've seen to `String-Select` involves `pipe-lining` and because I've set `$output` from a function, it doesn't appear to work (pipelining).

UPDATE: example of source text

```
# begin build properties
# autogenerated by buildinfo.sh
ro.build.id=IMM76D
ro.build.display.id=N861V1.0.0B09
ro.build.version.incremental=20121128.160026.30230
ro.build.version.sdk=15
# etc ...
```

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
$output.value | select-string -simplematch -pattern "ro.product".
```

If this doesn't work, then $output.value likely doesn't contain what you think it contains. It's also  possible that the source file is using unix line endings (LF) in which case it may well be treated as a single line. Convert it to use CRLF and try again.

Comment: Should you specify `SimpleMatch` or use escaping within the pattern? I *suspect* the current answer would also match "roxproduct" for example, if the pattern is being treated as a regular expression.

Comment: You're completely right. At this point, it's a lost cause but I'll correct it nonetheless.